# Android Facebook request using OpenGraphObject interface class

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Hi i have 2 interfaces:

```
public interface SpendAction extends OpenGraphAction{
    @PropertyName("namespace:transport") // I tried @PropertyName("transport") or without property
    public void setTransport(OGObject object);
    public OGObject getTransport();

}
```

And

```
public interface OGObject extends OpenGraphObject{
    @PropertyName("namespace:hours")
    public void setHours(int hours);
    @PropertyName("namespace:minutes")
    public void setMinutes(int minutes);
    @PropertyName("namespace:seconds")
    public void setSeconds(int seconds);
    public int getHours();
    public int getMinutes();
    public int getSeconds();
    public void setUrl(String url);
    public String getUrl();
    public void setTitle(String title);
    public String getTitle();
    public void setDescription(String message);
    public String getDescription();
}
```

1st is an OpenGraphAction and 2nd one is object. I'm creating interfaces this way:

```
SpendAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(SpendAction.class);
OGObject object = GraphObject.Factory.create(OGObject.class);
```

Then I'm setting object after filling it with data, url, title description etc.

```
action.setTransport(object); 
// I've tried to replace this with action.addProperty("transport", object) and action.addProperty("namespace:transport", object") 
//also action.setType("transport") and action.setType("namespace:transport)
action.setExplicitlyShared(true);
```

Facebook request creation:

```
Request request = new Request(
    Session.getActiveSession(),
    "me/namespace:spent",
    null,
    HttpMethod.POST,
    new Request.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            if(response != null && response.getError() != null) Log.d("Facebook Share", "Error message:" + response.getError().getErrorCode() + ", " + response.getError().getErrorMessage());
            if(response != null && response.getGraphObject() != null){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
);
request.setGraphObject(action);
request.executeAsync();
```

And I'm getting following error:

```
Error message:1611072, The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least one of the following properties must be specified: tv, transport, friends, studying, reading, shopping, cooking, cleaning, work, internet, personal_care, sport, sleeping, social_media, childcare, petcare, loo, games, sex, fun, hangover, smoking, eating.
```

I've already tried to set type for action, messed around with propertyname and nothing worked. 
On facebook I have my story and there I have my custom object with some custom fields (hours, minutes, seconds).

Sharing custom story is working for me when I'm creating json object (String). But not with these interfaces.